Python/win32crypt, "Access is denied" when trying to save a certificate to "local machine" Windows store, but working with "current user" store
Solved: I just had to select run as administrator for PyCharm and the executable.
I have a Python program that creates a self-signed certificate, and now I am trying to add a feature that saves that same certificate to the Windows "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" folder in the "Certificates - Local Computer" store. I have it working when saving to the "Current User" certificate store, but that's it. When I try to save the local machine store, I get this access denied message:
(-2147024891, 'PyCERTSTORE::CertAddEncodedCertificateToStore', 'Access is denied.')
Here's the function that takes in a certificate as a string:
CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM = 0x0000000A
CERT_STORE_OPEN_EXISTING_FLAG = 0x00004000
CERT_STORE_MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_FLAG = 0x00001000
CRYPT_STRING_BASE64HEADER = 0x00000000
CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER_ACCOUNT = 0x00010000
CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE = 0x00020000
X509_ASN_ENCODING = 0x00000001
CERT_STORE_ADD_REPLACE_EXISTING = 3
CERT_CLOSE_STORE_FORCE_FLAG = 0x00000001

def save_cert_to_store(cert_to_save: str) -> None:
    cert_byte = win32crypt.CryptStringToBinary(
        cert_to_save,
        CRYPT_STRING_BASE64HEADER
    )[0]

    store = win32crypt.CertOpenStore(
        CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM,
        0,
        None,
        CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE | CERT_STORE_MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_FLAG,
        "Root"
    )

    try:
        store.CertAddEncodedCertificateToStore(
            X509_ASN_ENCODING,
            cert_byte,
            CERT_STORE_ADD_REPLACE_EXISTING
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        store.CertCloseStore(CERT_CLOSE_STORE_FORCE_FLAG)

I suspect the problem is with this line: CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE | CERT_STORE_MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_FLAG, but I've tried different combinations of things here with the same results. I see that CERT_STORE_MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_FLAG starts with write permissions, which I assume I want here, since I am adding to the store, so I'm confused as to why it's giving me access denied. I've also tried CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE | CERT_STORE_OPEN_EXISTING_FLAG.
I'm also not sure what the difference is of using "Root" and "My". I've tried both. edit: Never mind, I found the answer to this.
I've looked at all of the other related posts on SO that are similar to this, but none are actually trying to save a new certificate to this store, only reading from.
I'm also wondering if this operation may just be blocked by Windows entirely.
I am referencing Microsoft's documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certopenstore
Note: To run this, you will need to pip install pywin32
Solved: I just had to select run as administrator for PyCharm and the executable.

Try CertOpenSystemStore. See the sample EhStorEnumerator.

There's no question here so I'm left to guess that you're asking whether the system offers an API for privilege escalation. The answer is "no".

My solution was to run the IDE and the executable as administrator
